# How do I get Ajax performance data with watir-webdriver-performance

Tags: ajax, performance, watir-webdriver, performance-testing

How do I get Ajax performance data with watir-webdriver-performance?

When I use below script I am getting the same result after triggered Ajax request.

```
require 'rubygems'
gem "selenium-webdriver"
require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'watir-webdriver-performance'

Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome.path = chromePath
b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome

b.goto 'Ajax Website'
p b.performance.summary

# click some ajax button to trigger server request 
p b.performance.summary

# click some ajax button to trigger server request 
p b.performance.summary

b.close
```

Output

```
{:time_to_first_byte=>396, :request=>395, :tcp_connection=>0, :app_cache=>0, :time_to_last_byte=>405, :redirect=>679, :response=>9, :dns=>0, :response_time=>6134, :dom_processing=>4041}

{:time_to_first_byte=>449, :request=>446, :tcp_connection=>0, :app_cache=>0, :time_to_last_byte=>458, :redirect=>2320, :response=>9, :dns=>0, :response_time=>3751, :dom_processing=>946}

{:time_to_first_byte=>449, :request=>446, :tcp_connection=>0, :app_cache=>0, :time_to_last_byte=>458, :redirect=>2320, :response=>9, :dns=>0, :response_time=>3751, :dom_processing=>946}
```

Comment: I did triggered some request to server with Ajax on the page.